# Why does using a variable cause the query to never complete?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of ~10 million bigints offset that are larger than a known constant.

I'd like to know how many numbers are within a range of the constant. (The actual query doesn't really matter). When I use the constant converted to a `bigint` the performance is acceptable (1 second). When I store the constant in a variable or a parameter the query never finishes. 
Here is the script to generate a sample table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('bigints', 'u') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE bigints;

WITH t
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM  (VALUES(1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1))f(n))
SELECT num = CONVERT(BIGINT, 123456789012)
             + ABS(BINARY_CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
INTO   bigints
FROM   t a,
       t b,
       t c,
       t d,
       t e,
       t f,
       t g
```

And here is an example of the failing query:

```
DECLARE @const BIGINT = CONVERT(BIGINT, 123456789012);

WITH t
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM  (VALUES(1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1))f(n)),
     tally(n)
     AS (SELECT @const
                + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         FROM   t a,
                t b,
                t c,
                t d)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Tally t
       JOIN bigints b
         ON t.n = b.num
```

If you replace `@const + row_number()` with the expression `CONVERT(BIGINT, 123456789012) + row_number()` the query will complete. Why does the introduction of the variable cause the query to run forever?

This was done on Sql Server 2012 and Sql Server 2014 both cause the same issue.

Comment: +1. Check the execution plans. When using the @const variable, my SQL Server generates a vastly different execution plan, including a lazy spool. That's probably what's killing your performance.

Comment: hmm you are right chipmunk. If you want to post it as an answer i'll consider it the answer.

Comment: Simplifying the T table to just two values shows that the plan has a lazy spool after the row number sequence projection after it completes in just 30 seconds. 
When it spools it reads from it 160000000 times and does a 9999999 rewinds. Probably murdering tempdb in the process. Why is a mystery to me.

Comment: BTW: Trace flag 4199 could well resolve this issue without the ugly workaround in my answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104693/3690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fast plan gets 10,000 rows going into the hash join on `bigints` with a bitmap filter.

The slow plan gets 10,000 rows going into a nested loops join onto a 10,000,000 table with an intermediate table spool.

10,000 executions against that spool are going to be slow.

It looks like the query optimiser doesn't give itself any choice but to use nested loops though.

Attempting to force the issue with an `INNER HASH JOIN` hint produces

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
>   defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
>   and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Indeed this issue can be seen in much simpler queries by adding a reference to a variable as below (also fails)

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1) = '';

SELECT *
FROM   master..spt_values T1
       INNER HASH JOIN master..spt_values T2
                    ON T1.name = (T2.name + @S);
```

This additional reference to a variable certainly shouldn't prevent a hash (or merge) join on a query with an equality predicate and this is a fixed bug (Relevant KB article - [Performance issues occur when the join predicate in your query has outer reference columns in SQL Server 2005 or in SQL Server 2008](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976410))

> SYMPTOMS
>
> You run a query in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or in Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2008, and the join predicate in the query has outer
>   reference columns. In this case, you may experience performance
>   issues, and the query cannot be completed.
>
> Note This issue does not occur in Microsoft SQL Server 2000.
>
> CAUSE
>
> The problem that is described in the "Symptoms" section occurs
>   because the database engine cannot generate a merge join or a hash
>   join. Therefore, a loop join is used instead. Using a loop join causes
>   the performance problem.

however you must be running on one of the builds (or later) described in the hotfix link (SQL Server 2005 SP3 CU7, 2008 RTM CU9, 2008 SP1 CU6) and must be running with trace flag 4199 enabled to take advantage of the fix (even up to and including SQL Server 2014).

Other less satisfactory work arounds are on 2008 CU5+ the [parameter embedding optimization](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) solves things with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

The following will get recompiled on each invocation treating the variable as though it was a constant and compilation succeeds with the desired faster plan.

```
DECLARE @const BIGINT = CONVERT(BIGINT, 123456789012);

WITH t
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM  (VALUES(1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),
                      (1))f(n)),
 tally(n)
     AS (SELECT @const
                + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         FROM   t a,
                t b,
                t c,
                t d)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Tally t
       INNER HASH JOIN bigints b
                    ON t.n = b.num
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Or even the following defeats the issue and allows the main join to use hash or merge at the cost of some extra plan complexity.

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1) = '';

SELECT *
FROM   master..spt_values T1
       INNER JOIN master..spt_values T2
                    ON T1.name = (T2.name + (SELECT MAX(@S)));
```

Comment: I had also had the same success by complicating the plan with a LEAD Cte with a lookforward of 0. changing the plan to this `;with t as (select * from(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
)f(n)),
tally as (select n=lead(n,0) over(order by (select n))
from (select @const  + row_number() over (order by (select a.n)) from t a,t b, t c, t d) tally(n))
select count(*)
from tally t
join bigints b
on n = num`, also yields a fast plan. The plan is much more complicated but it appears to have chosen a bitmap again.

Comment: @MichaelB - Inspired by that I took your original query and changed it to `SELECT (SELECT MAX(@const)) + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` and back to a hash join again.

Comment: weird. Why does the useless aggregate cause the performance boost? In the `Lead` case its forces the elements to be shoved into a in-memory spool table which probably helps makes it chose to use a hash join.

Comment: @MichaelB - Not sure - My guess is that it achieves some level of indirection such that the new derived column has different properties and it is not regarded as being associated with the variable any more.